# How to prevent concurrent call in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

Deal all, i am facing one problem in spring mvc. From one of our external system say payment gateway will call us [/getRespFromExternal] after their transaction completed, unfortunately they are calling us more than one time at time.

In the method getRespFromExternal, we are calling internal webservice to process payment acknowledgement, before WS call completed itself i get another duplicate call from external system. So i get payInd is null in payResponse method in controller. after first call [WS call] finished then /payResponse from controller is not even calling . Sorry for my english. Please advice me.

Service Method called by External System:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getRespFromExternal",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getRespFromExternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse,HttpSession session){
    if (httpRequest != null && session.getAttribute("extRespId") == null) {
        session.setAttribute("extRespId", httpRequest.getParameter("tranID"));
        // internal web service call
        callInternalWS(); // to process payment
        before processing above WS method i get another call from external[/getRespFromExternal] for second time;
        session.setAttribute("payInd", "Y");

        return "redirect:/payResponse/";
    }
    return "redirect:/payResponse/";
}
```

Controller Method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payResponse/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView payResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    String payInd = (String) session.getAttribute("payInd");
    System.out.println("payInd --> "+payInd);
    if (payInd != null && payInd.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y") ) {

    }   
}
```

Comment: Does it provide some sort of transaction ID?

Comment: Yes they are providing transaction is

Comment: @Chrylis any ideo or solution..

Comment: How can you detect the duplicate call in `/getRespFromExternal `? By `tranID`?

Comment: @zico.. yes getting 3 calls for same tran id..

Comment: @DEADEND you can use [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to store `tran id` before process WS and remove the id whenever you completed the process. So that whenever same `tran id` comes between WS call + processing you can easily check if the `tran id` already send to WS or not.

Comment: Thank you @Zico.. If i use ConcurrentHashMap as instance variable then if i get multiple call at method /getRespFromExternal for same tran id, tran id is exist in that map during second because its instance variable right & another problem is second call ie duplicate call is not waiting for first call completion, it will redirect to response jsp before first call job completion. i used synchronization but all different tran is is waiting in queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting multiple calls to your service with the same transaction if, that should be treated as an error.

I assume that you are using a transactional database to record the payments.

If so, then you could make the transaction id a unique key in the database.  If the SQL insert or update to record the transaction fails due to a duplicate key, redirect to a different URL to report the error.